# Magento 2 Simple Product customizable options store wise import not working

Tags: magento2.4.3.p1

I have a Magento 2 wesbite with multiple websites and multiple store views.

For the simple products I need to import customizable options store wise. When I import custom options store wise it's not importing or updating custom options.

When I import without store_view_code it's working fine.

For the import I'm using default feature of Magento 2 System -> Data Transfer -> Import

Answer (score 1):

Try this

If you're experiencing issues with importing or updating custom options for simple products in Magento 2, specifically when importing store-wise, there are a few things you can check and consider:

1.Verify CSV File Format: Ensure that your CSV file is properly formatted and follows the correct structure for importing custom options. Each custom option should have its own row, and make sure the required columns such as **sku,** **store_view_code**, **option_title**, and **option_type** are present and populated correctly.

2.**Check Store View Codes:** Confirm that the store view codes in your CSV file match the store view codes in your Magento 2 instance exactly. Any discrepancies may result in issues with importing custom options for specific store views.

3.**Check Scope Settings:** Custom options have different scope settings in Magento 2, such as Global, Website, or Store View. Ensure that the scope settings for your custom options are properly configured to match your requirements. For store-wise import, make sure the scope is set to the appropriate Store View.

4.**Import Behavior:** When using the Data Transfer feature in Magento 2, pay attention to the import behavior options available during the import process. Make sure you select the correct behavior, such as "Append Complex Data" or "Replace Existing Complex Data," based on your desired outcome.

5.**Check Error Logs:** After attempting the import, check the system logs and error logs in Magento 2 for any relevant error messages or warnings. This can help you identify any specific issues or errors that are occurring during the import process.

Comment: I have checked all the things. it's fine but still not working.